# minimize a function that contains an array parameter

Tags: python, minimize

I am trying to minimize a function that contains an array parameter.

I tried to simplify my problem in the following example. The function `Func` contains the parameter `c2 = linspace(-1,1,10)`. The optimization is about thet1, phai1, thet2, and phai2 so that they are bounded by the interval `(0,2*pi)`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo

a1 = 0
c1 = 0
cc2 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
alpha1 = 1+a1/3

def Func(ang):
    
    thet1 = ang[0]
    phai1 = ang[1]
    thet2 = ang[2]
    phai2 = ang[3]
    
    RhoABC = np.array([[[1-a1,0,thet1,0,0,0,0,c1],[0,alpha1,0,0,phai2,0,c2,0],[0,0,alpha1,0,0,c2,thet2,0],[0,0,0,alpha1,c2,0,0,0],[0,phai1,0,c2,alpha1,0,0,0],[0,0,c2,0,0,alpha1,0,thet2],[0,c2,0,0,0,0,alpha1,0],[c1,0,0,phai1,0,0,0,1-a1]] for c2 in cc2])   
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(RhoABC)  
    return w[1]

angs0 = [.4*np.pi,1.9*np.pi,1.2*np.pi,.7*np.pi]

bnd = (0*np.pi,2*np.pi)
bnds = (bnd,bnd,bnd,bnd)

result = spo.minimize(Func,angs0,bounds=bnds)
```

the output is:
ValueError: too many axes: 2 (effrank=2), expected rank=1

I just want to plot the minimized value (fun) as a function of c2. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1):

The function to be minimized should return a float (see [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)). However, `Func` returns a 1d array instead of a float. That is because `RhoABC` is 3d, so `w` is 2d, which makes `w[1]` a 1d array.